# how to get array in java android from web service with ksoap

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap

I have a java web service which i want to use with an android client for that am using ksoap.
My web service gives an answer which look like this :

```
java.util.List : "[mobilerestaurantbooking.RMenu@66eb63f8,
mobilerestaurantbooking.RMenu@67f06391,
mobilerestaurantbooking.RMenu@5718f9e6,
mobilerestaurantbooking.RMenu@28be97b6,
mobilerestaurantbooking.RMenu@78da429f]"
```

that is something like id, name , category,.... and pass it to my application but the output is like anyType{}

this is my code in android

```
        try {
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject)soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
            List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
            int count = response.getPropertyCount();

            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                if(response.getProperty(i) != null)
                    categories.add(response.getProperty(i).toString());
            }
```

who know what should i do?

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087480/xml-parsing-using-kasoap2-android/10089614#10089614. I think it's useful for you.

Comment: try modifying like this example                           SoapObject yourResponseObject = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;  SoapObject array = (SoapObject) yourResponseObject .getProperty(0);     SoapObject DisplayName= (SoapObject)array .getProperty(0);  SoapObject Email= (SoapObject)array .getProperty(1);

Comment: unfortunately i don't get answer
i used like that but i don`t have any response

Answer (score 1):

```
public class KSOAP extends Activity 
{
    ListView list;
    ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String>  arrayadapter;

    Button btn;
    TextView tv,tv2,tv3; 
    EditText no1,no2;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
//tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

no1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
no2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/" ;    
        //"http://vladozver.org/";
        String METHOD_NAME = "GetStringList"; //"GetSumOfTwoIntsList";//
        String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetStringList";  
        //"http://vladozver.org/GetSumOfTwoInts";
        String URL = "http://192.168.0.203/recharge_service/service.asmx";
        //"http://192.168.0.203/Recharge_Service/Service.asmx";


        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

//      PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
//      pi.setName("Operand1");
//      pi.setValue(Integer.parseInt(no1.getText().toString()));
//      pi.setType(int.class);
//      Request.addProperty(pi);
//
//      PropertyInfo pi2 = new PropertyInfo();
//      pi2.setName("Operand2");
//      pi2.setValue(Integer.parseInt(no2.getText().toString()));
//      pi2.setType(int.class);
//      Request.addProperty(pi2);


        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
        try
        {
        AndroidHttpTransport transp = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
        transp.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        SoapObject obj1 = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

        SoapObject obj2 =(SoapObject) obj1.getProperty(0);


        for (int i = 0; i< obj2.getPropertyCount(); i++) 
            { 
                // int id1 = Integer.parseInt(obj2.getProperty(0).toString());
               String id1=obj2.getProperty(0).toString();

               if(id1 != "")
               { 
                 arraylist.add( id1);   

               }
                /* tv3.setText(id3);*/
            }


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        { tv.setText(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //tv.setText(""+ count);



               list.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
    }
});

        arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arraylist );
       list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}


}
```

Comment: Good solution, but you have to correct the index of obj2,getProerty(0) and use i instead of 0

Answer (score 0):

and also i do it like it but i dont have any record in menu class.

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;


Menu[] menus = new Menu[result.getPropertyCount()];

for (int i = 0; i < menus.length; i++) { 
   SoapObject so = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(0); 
   Menu s = new Menu(); 
   s.setID(Integer.parseInt(so.getProperty(0).toString())); 
   s.setName(so.getProperty(1).toString()); 
   s.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(so.getProperty(2).toString())); 
   s.setCategory(so.getProperty(3).toString()); 
   menus[i] = s; 
 }
```

Comment: when change it 
         SoapObject result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
to     
         SoapObject result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponce;
the length is 0

Answer (score 0):

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
Menu[] menus = new Menu[result.getPropertyCount()];
for (int i = 0; i < menus.length; i++) {
SoapObject so = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(i);
    ID = so.getProperty(0).toString();
    Name = so.getProperty(1).toString();
    price = so.getProperty(2).toString();
    Catagory = so.getProperty(3).toString();
}
```

and after get the result in one object:

```
SoapPrimitive so = (SoapPrimitive) so.getProperty(1);
firstlist[i] = so.getPropertyAsString(0).toString();
```